# Kendo DateTimePicker Angular 7 grid date editor TypeError: date.getTime is not a function

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am getting TypeError: date.getTime is not a function while binding the date to the Kendo Datatimepicker.

```
core.js:15713 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: date.getTime is not a function
TypeError: date.getTime is not a function
    at cloneDate (clone-date.js:13)
    at DatePickerComponent.push../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs/dist/es/datepicker/datepicker.component.js.DatePickerComponent.writeValue (datepicker.component.js:384)
```

The date returned by the web.api is in the following format

```
"2004-04-15T19:00:00"
```

I presume it is complaining because it is not a valid date format hence tried to convert it below but getting error forEach is not a function. I have commented the code below. Could somebody tell me how do i resolve the issue.

I tried to convert the string to date

```
 getFundDetails(selectedFundId: number) {


            if (selectedFundId != null) {
            this.fundService.getFundDetails(selectedFundId).subscribe((data: IFund[]) => {
                // data.forEach((d) => {d.InceptionDate = new Date(d.InceptionDate); });
                this.FundDetails = data;
                this.SelectedFundId = this.FundDetails.FundId;

            });
        }
    }
```

Viewmodel

```
 public class FundViewModelNew
    {

        public int FundId { get; set; }
        public string FundName { get; set; }
        public bool? IsAnonymous { get; set; }
        public string BloombergTicker { get; set; }
        public int? InvestmentStatusId { get; set; }
        public string InvestmentStatusName { get; set; }
        public int? FlagShipFundId { get; set; }
        public string FlagShipFundName { get; set; }
        public  DateTime? InceptionDate { get; set; }
        public int? AccountMandateId { get; set; }
        public string AccountMandateName { get; set; }
        public int? VehicleTypeId { get; set; }
        public string VehicleTypeName { get; set; }

}
```

Interface

```
export interface IFund {
    FundId: number;
    FundName: string;
    IsAnonymous: boolean;
    BloombergTicker: string;
    InvestmentStatusId: number;
    InvestmentStatusName: string;
    FlagShipFundId: number;
    InceptionDate: Date;
    AccountMandateId: number;
    AccountMandateName: string;
    VehicleTypeId: number;
    VehicleTypeName: string;

}
```

Comment: Do you get any solution?